# Exciton elements and exciton chemistry

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, semiconductor-physics, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

An exciton is a bound state of an electron and a hole, much like a hydrogen atom is a bound state of a proton and an electron.

Can a "helium" exciton be created, such that two electrons are bound to two holes? How about other exciton "elements"?

If these elements can be created (and momentarily stabilized), can they interact with each other if they exist within a quantum dot? If they are somehow independent? Can we expect the "exciton chemistry" to be the same as normal chemistry, with "exciton elements" replacing atom elements (with much shorter stability times, of course)? Or is there a theoretical model that suggests otherwise?

Thank you!

Comment: You are thinking to what is called a bi-exciton. See here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/biexciton

Answer (score 2):

The exitonic molecule composed of two electrons and two holes was seen by [J.R. Haynes](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.17.860) in 1966 in silicon. Since electron-electron or hole-hole binding would be very different from nucleon binding, it does not qualify as 'helium'.

Comment: Thank you! How about other "elements" (excitonic parallels, i.e. a 3 electrons, 3 holes structures)? Can we expect exciton "chemistry"? Will it be similiar to actual chemistry?

Comment: I'm not sure what the current state-of-the art is - note that those measurements were already at 3K. By 1973 the electron-hole droplet had been observed, a metallic condensation of excitons. See http://physicstoday.scitation.org/toc/pto/26/12?expanded=26 pg. 17 for an early note on that.